# Ship v.s. Deliver

Tags: vocabulary

I'm reading a book published weeks ago. The author substituted 'deliver' for 'ship'

For example

> Python **ships** with several stack implementations that each have slightly different characteristics.
>
> You see, the trouble is that Python **ships** with an extensive set of data structures in its standard library.

In Oxford dict [ship](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ship) means Send by some other means of transport or by mail.

I  seach the entire book without a 'deliver' found.

I am not a native speaker,should I apply 'ship' instead of 'deliver' as if to perform more natively?

Answer (score 5):

With respect to physical goods, "ship" and "deliver" have very different commercial meanings. A seller "ships" when the seller puts the goods into the hands of a carrier, just as the dictionary says. A seller "delivers" when the seller puts the goods into the hands of the buyer. If a carrier or some other party facilitates the physical transfer between original seller and ultimate buyer, the time of shipment and the time of delivery necessarily differ. Moreover, in many cases, a seller is obligated by contract to do no more than transfer to a designated or appropriate carrier.

In the world of software, things may not be as clear cut as they are in the physical world, but it still usually is correct that the creator does not communicate directly with the seller. The creator transfers the information to someone other than the ultimate buyer, e.g., an Internet service provider. "Shipping" means when the creator loses control over the information.

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying the author used "ships" and you would have used "delivers" or the other way round? In any case, in this context, there's a fairly specific and common meaning for a product name followed by "ships with" so these sound right to me, and "Python delivers with" would sound wrong. It's similar to saying it "comes with."

If you want to be strict about it, I don't think anyone buys Python in a store and has it sent to them in any way, so it's probably definitely a kind of idiom that means "comes with" or "was made with" in this context, but it's not wrong and "delivers with" definitely would be wrong.

In other contexts, ship and deliver are often synonyms, but the subject of ship can be the thing that *was* shipped. For example, I can say:

I shipped Python to you.
I delivered Python to you.

The result of these actions can be that "Python shipped," but it can't be that "Python delivered."

Comment: ...unless they mean that *Python* ***delivers,*** with (insert marketing buzzwords here). But I agree, *ships with* in these examples seems to mean that as packaged, it includes these things.

Answer (score 0):

With most products "**shipping**" means "**to be sent for delivery**" which means that the author doesn't have the product anymore. The second phase can either include a purchaser to whom the product will be delivered, or a courier who will deliver the product the buyer.

With software the situation is similar but it may not exactly mean that the author hasn't his hands on his product once he's shipped it. Basically, shipping a software means building the final package or in other words making the installer for instance, which can afterward be placed on the author's website or online market for instance. However, this may or may not be the exact meaning in all cases. Usually, shipping a software means "**placing it on sale**" or "**making it available for delivery**".

If we consider a platform or an OS the situation is similar. Even Games are based on the same structure.

Note: "**with**" is playing a major role in telling us about the inclusion of components in the final product. For instance, "**Some games are shipped with a map editor and additional software like video drivers, redistributive packs and the DirectX installer**".